# Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch warning in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know this question was asked quite a few times before but they didn't resolve my problem.
I'm developing a simple calculator app targeted at ios 7 and further with Single-View Application. I'm using XCode 5. Currently my simulator looks completely black. Here are my relevant methods:

```
//AppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    return YES;

}

//main.m

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you linked your viewcontroller object in your storyboard to your viewcontroller class?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. I'm really new to XCode and Objective-c. What I've done so far is creating a bunch of buttons on storyboard and ctrl-drag them to the controller class' buttonClicked method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

View the above image.

Have you linked your viewcontroller object in your storyboard to your viewcontroller class?

Comment: Yes, when i click on the yellow ViewController button it looks like the image.

Comment: @Umut Have you actually added any objects to the view? And did you make the background color black?

Comment: Ok. Somehow the global tint was set to black. i changed it to white and the warning disappeared. View came back.